# Recycler View doesn't show any item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display contacts in a Fragment but the `recycler view` doesn't show any item. Despite having items in the list recycler view is not showing any item. I am not sure what I have done wrong as the app does not crash when it is running.

**Here is The Code**

```
public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    UsersAdapter adapter;
    List<Users> actualuserList;
    List<String> contactsList;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.userRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        contactsList = new ArrayList<>();
        actualuserList = new ArrayList<>();


        return view;
    }


    private void getContactList() {
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            if (contactsList.contains(phone)) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            } else {
                contactsList.add(phone);
            }
        }
        getActualUser();
        Log.d("contact: ", String.valueOf(contactsList.size()));

    }

    private void getActualUser() {
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        for (String number : contactsList) {
            Query query = reference.orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo(number);
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    actualuserList.clear();
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Users user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                            actualuserList.add(user);
                        }
                        Log.d("actual: ", String.valueOf(actualuserList.size()));
                        adapter = new UsersAdapter(getContext(), actualuserList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getContactList();
    }
}
```

In the Log statement, it is showing `actual:1` that means there is an item.

**Here is Adapter Code**

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    List<Users> mList;

    public UsersAdapter(Context mContext, List<Users> mList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mList = mList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.display_contacts, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Users users = mList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(users.getUsername());
        holder.number.setText(users.getPhoneNumber());
        String url = users.getProfilephotoURL();
        if (url.equals(""))
            holder.circleImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_user);
        else
            Glide.with(mContext).load(url).into(holder.circleImageView);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ChatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", users.getUsername());
            intent.putExtra("firendPhoneNumber", users.getPhoneNumber());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, number;
        CircleImageView circleImageView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactNumber);
            circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        }
    }
}
```

**Logs**

```
2020-07-27 14:52:51.651 25366-25366/com.mycompany.newchatapp D/contact:: 167

2020-07-27 14:52:51.670 25366-25366/com.mycompany.newchatapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

2020-07-27 14:52:51.691 25366-25366/com.mycompany.newchatapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for status found on class com.mycompany.newchatapp.Model.Users

2020-07-27 14:52:51.691 25366-25366/com.mycompany.newchatapp D/actual:: 1

2020-07-27 14:52:51.723 25366-25366/com.mycompany.newchatapp W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for status found on class com.mycompany.newchatapp.Model.Users

2020-07-27 14:52:51.723 25366-25366/com.mycompany.newchatapp D/actual:: 1
```

Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like you didn't call `setAdapter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, I've faced this issue very recently and I was using as global List variable as well and the list wasn't empty, even the adpater was not empty but `RecyclerView` wasn't showing any data until second `adpater.notifyDataSetchanged()`.

I'd found an answer here on this site that said "create a new list variable" and it worked.

Try making the `actualUserList` a local variable as in your `onDataChange()`,

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    List<Users> actualuserList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            Users user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            actualuserList.add(user);
        }
        Log.d("actual: ", String.valueOf(actualuserList.size()));
        adapter = new UsersAdapter(getContext(), actualuserList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, you can also try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting up the adapter as `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Also, set the adapter in `onCreatedView()` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in this `onDataChange()`.

Comment: Making it local worked. But If I call setAdapter method in onCreatedView then I have switch fragment twice or thrice to make items appear.

Comment: @HarshAshra actually you don't, `notifyDataSetChanged` can manage updating items in recycler for you

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you forgot to set adapter.

In `onCreateView` method put something like:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new UsersAdapter(this.getActivity(), getContactList()));
```

UPD:
Before that, make `getContactList()` return relevant dataset. Do not set adapter after initializing recycler view.

Comment: I have set the adapter in getActualUser method.

Comment: You should not set adapter in that method, it is actually a design flaw. I suggest you to set it in the onCreateView or  in onViewCreated directly

Comment: There is one thing I noted whenever I open friends fragment it shows item for a second and then disappear.

Comment: I have added the Logs please check it

Comment: The line of logs tells you "no adapter attached, skipping layout". It clearly means that you should set adapter earlier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218670/discussion-between-harsh-ashra-and-steyrix).